# What and how each line of code do to redirect URL without backslash in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know the below code redirects url that ends with "/" to the same url but without "/".

It is for my personal knowledge that I am trying to dig-in to know in more detail about what the below code is doing and how is is it doing.

Can someone please explain each line of code in plain English as I am a starter to programming.

I had asked my lecturer and my tutors about it but I could not understand in detail.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.substr(-1) == '/' && req.path.length > 1) {
        var query = req.url.slice(req.path.length);
        res.redirect(301, req.path.slice(0, -1) + query);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line declares a function in express. 
The second line checks that the url, supplied as an argument (req.path), contains '/' as the last item, and has a length greater than 1. In other words, it checks that the url has a /, but is not just /. 
The third line sets the variable query equal to another argument passed as req.url, sliced to the length of req.path. In other words, if req.path was /someurl/, and req.url was ?authenticated, query would be set to ?authenti 
The fourth line redirects to a url comprised of req.path without the /, plus the query. So, in the last example, it would redirect to /someurl?authenti. It also sets a 301 status code, indicating that a redirect occurred. 
The last line adds an else condition in case the check on line 2 failed, so it basically just skips over the execution of the entire function in that case